# i used aget to return value at the index/indices. but it is not working,how can return value in clojure?

Tags: clojure, return-value

I want to return value off array in Clojure. I find `aget` but it not work the error is `"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method found: aget"`.

my code

```
(def v ["Joan", "Ronan", "Nikita", "Augustus"])
```

or

```
(def v (object-array ["Joan" "Ronan" "Nikita" "Augustus"]))
```

and

```
(aget v 0)
```

I get this error: `"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method found: aget"`

Answer (score 1):

The first example `(def v ["Joan", "Ronan", "Nikita", "Augustus"])` will give that error because v is a vector, not an array.

The second example should work fine.

Comment: To index into the first def of v, call `(get v 0)`.

Comment: thanks now working but it always happen to me before it not worked

Comment: it can see here that for `(aget v 0)` is ok for zero but for other indices is not working. for example  `(aget v 1)`